# Batch File not working after modification

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that creates folders in other client folders. I added one additional folder to be made now the bat file won't work. Am I missing something here?

```
@echo off

set Dir=y:\(Directory of companies)
set Year=(The year I want the folders added to)


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /ad/b !Dir!') do (
    if not exist "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!" (
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!"
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax"
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax\Estimated_Tax"
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax\Info_for_tax_return"  
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Year_End_Planning"
    )
  )
)
```

`Info_for_tax_return` is the new line I added that made the bat file stop working.
Appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: After you add it, in what way does it "stop working"? Any errors? Are any of the other folders (still) created? If you remove the line does it work as expected again?

Comment: I run cmd with elevated privileges, run the .bat file and I get, The system cannot find the path specified. If it helps these folders are made to a mapped drive to Sharepoint 2007. If I remove the line now, I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have more closing parentheses than opening ones in your `for` block:

```
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /ad/b !Dir!') do ( **<-1**
    if not exist "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!" ( **<-2**
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!"
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax"
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax\Estimated_Tax"
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax\Info_for_tax_return"  
    md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Year_End_Planning"
    ) **<-1**
  ) **<-2**
) **<-3**
```

Remove the extra closing bracket and try again:

```
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /ad/b !Dir!') do (
    if not exist "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!" (
        md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!"
        md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax"
        md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax\Estimated_Tax"
        md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Tax\Info_for_tax_return"  
        md "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!\Year_End_Planning"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` because you do not need delayed expansion enabled
- `set "Year=2015"` enclosed in double quotes to ensure no additional unwanted white spaces
- `set "Dir=y:\Directory of companies"` as well
- `md "%Dir%\%%D\%Year%" 2>nul` to suppress error messages (redirect them to hell with `2>nul`) if target directory exists. Therefore you need not test whether it exists or not
- your `if not exist "!Dir!\%%D\!Year!" (...)` disallowed creating directories whed added a line and launched more than once time...

This script should work for you.

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "Dir=y:\Directory of companies"
set "Year=2015"
:: (The year I want the folders added to)

for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /ad/b %Dir%') do (
    md "%Dir%\%%D\%Year%" 2>nul
    md "%Dir%\%%D\%Year%\Tax" 2>nul
    md "%Dir%\%%D\%Year%\Tax\Estimated_Tax" 2>nul
    md "%Dir%\%%D\%Year%\Tax\Info_for_tax_return" 2>nul  
    md "%Dir%\%%D\%Year%\Year_End_Planning" 2>nul
)
endlocal
```